# About history.replaceState (HTML5) and location.href in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

if I save location.href as

```
var h = location.href;
```

Then perform `history.replaceState`  or `pushState` in (HTML5) to another href, lets say h2

And if we check h and h2, you will see them equal (in Chrome and Firefox, my IE seems not support HTML5 yet)

ok, my question is:

In this situation, how I know `location.href` is real or fake (by pushed).

**[EDIT]**

I add a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/W4bb3/

Comment: what do you mean by "real or fake"?

Comment: *"And if we check h and h2, you will see them equal"* - What do you mean by that?

Comment: location.href should be the URL of current page. After perform history functions which HTML5 supports, the location.href changed (but the page not reload), so I think its faked which means not real page url

Comment: I add a sample, check it (you need to support HTML5 browser, sort of) http://jsfiddle.net/W4bb3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't at the moment in all browsers. There is the [`history.state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history#Syntax) method in firefox:

```
history.pushState({'foo': 'bar'}, null, 'test')
history.state // will return { foo="bar"}
```

So you can test that the state is not `null`, which will be if it was not set via `pushState`.

Comment: Thanks. Check `history.state` is a good idea, However, cannot get it work: http://jsfiddle.net/W4bb3/5/

Comment: Cause you set first argument in the pushState call to `""` which is a falsy value in JavaScript.

Comment: You right. Which also means this method is not reliable.  I am working on a script to place on 3rd party site for tracking purpose. So I want to get real URL, and I cannot know if if pushState get called

Comment: However, still a good idea, I can check if its null. Many people just copy code from internet, so most likely they will use ""(empty string) for the first parameter